# How can I efficiently tell if an index is a complete cartesian product

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [list('abb'), list('xxy')])

print(df)

     0  1
a x  1  2
b x  3  4
  y  5  6
```

The index of `df` is **not** a cartesian product.  I can generate one with

```
cp = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, df.index.names)
```

But what is an efficient way to determine if the existing index is "complete" or if all unique values are present for all levels?

---

This has implications on how I would choose to `unstack` a series or dataframe.  If the index is sorted and a complete cartesian product, then I could employ numpy techniques to more efficiently `unstack` as seen by @Divakar [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44142801/2336654).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take an analytical approach to determining if your index is exactly a Cartesian product by checking if the index is unique, and has the right number of elements:

```
df.index.is_unique and (len(df) == np.prod(df.index.levshape))
```

This won't cover the case where your index contains a Cartesian product (i.e. a Cartesian product with duplicate indices).  You could mix in `drop_duplicates` to handle that case though, along the lines of:

```
len(df.index.drop_duplicates()) == np.prod(df.index.levshape)
```

Comment: I didn't realize `levshape` existed :-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to check the number of rows and compare against the product of lengths of index levels -

```
df.shape[0]==np.prod(list(map(len, df.index.levels)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Re-index the df using a Multiindex with the full product and then compare length with the original df.

len(df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels),fill_value=np.nan))==len(df)
```